# togetherJS on web application using login/password

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, togetherjs

I am integrating togetherJS for building co-browsing experience for my web application.

As my application requires user login (cookie and session) I am not able to share logged IN browser session with another user(s).

When user1 is logged-in on his/her browser and shares session with user2, user2 is presented again with login screen because user1 client/server cookie/session is not known by user2 browser.

I understand togetherJS sync browser only thru URLs (via web sockets) but wanted to understand whether there is any better way to sync browser cookie/server-session between multiple users using togetherJS or something else?

Comment: did you find any solution? Did you find any other framework that helps on this task?

Comment: No, togetherJS will be on URL level and cannot be used for login applications directly, you can still use it if you can share web/cookie/session details between browsers (security perspective not recommended). Now I am using MutationObserver where two browsers are in-sync by DOM level events.

Comment: any framework in special? Thanks for your comment and regards!

Comment: Try mutation-summary, you can modify as per your need, Thanks!

Comment: Tks @Rushik, I'll try!